Relative quadratic extension not ramified at primes above 2
I am trying to understand the proof of Proposition 4.2 in this paper of Mazur and Rubin. In it, given some ideal of a base field $K$, they construct a quadratic extension $F/K$ (corresponding to a quadratic twist of an elliptic curve) for which the dimension of the 2-Selmer group of the curve and of the quadratic twist by $F$ are the same.  My question is about some class field theory in the proof of the proposition.
Setup: Fix a number field $K$ and an elliptic curve $E/K$ such that $E(K)[2]=0$. Let $\Delta$ be the discriminant of $E$. Let $K(8\Delta\infty)$ be the ray class field of $K$ with modulus $8\Delta$ and all archimedian places of $K$. Let $M=K(E[2])$ be $K$ adjoined with the coordinates of 2-torsion points of $E$. Let $S$ be all of the element of order 3 in $\mathrm{Gal}(M/K) = S_3 ~\text{or}~ \mathbf{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.
Further define the following three sets of ideal of $K$:

$P$: all primes $\mathfrak p$ of $K$ so that $\mathfrak p$ is unramified in $MK(8\Delta\infty)/K$ and $Frob_{\mathfrak p}(M/K) \subset S$.
$N$: all square-free products of primes from $P$.
$N_1$ all ideals $\mathfrak{a} \in N$ for which $[\mathfrak{a}, K(8\Delta\infty)/K]=1$ where $[\cdot, K(8\Delta\infty)/K$ is the global Artin symbol.

Claim:
The proof starts with an ideal $\mathfrak{a} \in N_1$.  The ideal $\mathfrak a$ is principal, with totally positive generator $\alpha \equiv 1 \mod 8\Delta$. Set $F=K(\sqrt{\alpha})$. The claim is then that $F$ splits at the following places

All primes of $K$ dividing $\Delta$, i.e. primes of bad reduction for $E$
All infinite places of $K$
All primes in $K$ above 2.

Question:  Why is the addition of 8 to the modulus of the ray class field of $K$ sufficient to guarantee that primes of $K$ above 2 must split in $F/K$?

Let $\mathfrak{p}$ be a place of $K$ above $2$. We wish to show that $\alpha$ is a square in $K_\mathfrak{p}$. Consider the polynomial $p=x^2-\alpha\in K_{\mathfrak{p}}[x]$, we wish to show that this has a solution in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Consider $1\in K_{\mathfrak{p}}$. We have that $|p(1)|_2\leq \frac{1}{8}$ because $p(1)\equiv 1^2-1\pmod 8$. On the other hand, we have $|p'(1)|_2=|2\cdot 1^2|_2=\frac{1}{2}$, so we establish the inequality $|p(1)|<|p'(1)|^2$. By a generalization of Hensel's lemma (see Wikipedia for example) this implies that $p(x)$ has a root in $K_{\mathfrak{p}}$.
Since $K_{\mathfrak{p}}(\sqrt{\alpha})/K_{\mathfrak{p}}$ is a trivial, $\mathfrak{p}$ is completely split in $K(\sqrt{\alpha})/K$.
